# in Python, reading & parsing a csv then printing - Why is it behaving differently than I expect?

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

Here is some code:

```
trained_nlp = spacy.load("models/output/model-best")

with open('Dog_Breed.csv') as f:
    s = f.read() # + '\n'  add trailing new line character

print('Here is the csv as string')
print(s)

doc = trained_nlp(s)

for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ is not None and ent.label_=='BREED' :
        sentence_breed = ' is a '
        print(ent.text + sentence_breed  + ent.label_ + ' and ')
    if ent.text is not None and ent.label_ == 'ORIGIN' :
        sentence_origin = ' has an '
        print ( sentence_origin + ent.label_ + ' of ' + ent.text)
```

Here is what gets printed

```
Here is the csv as string
,Dog Breed,Origin
0,Boykin Spaniel,South Carolina
1,German Shepherd,Germany
2,Border Collie,Scotland

 has an ORIGIN of ,Dog
Breed, is a BREED and 
 has an ORIGIN of Origin

0,Boykin Spaniel is a BREED and 
 has an ORIGIN of ,South
1,German Shepherd is a BREED and 
 has an ORIGIN of ,
 has an ORIGIN of Germany
2,Border Collie is a BREED and 
 has an ORIGIN of ,
 has an ORIGIN of Scotland
```

Some anomalies:

1. The spacy model labels seem always present - but I want to ignore the first link, ",Dog Breed,Origin", since there are no matches. You can see I've struggled with that using the None keyword
2. Note that "South Carolina" gets truncated, but "Boykin Spaniel" does not?!? Despite this, the first output is well formed - I get a sentence like I want, like "X is a BREED, and has an ORIGIN of Y", no repeats.
3. For rows 1 and 2, however, I get the dummy line of "has an ORIGIN of ,".

I'm better at understanding language models than I am an tricky inner loops in Python ;-)

I was expecting something ike:

```
0,Boykin Spaniel is a BREED and has an ORIGIN of South Carolina
1,German Shepherd is a BREED and has an ORIGIN of Germany
2,Border Collie is a BREED and has an ORIGIN of Scotland
```

Comment: it is really unclear why you are using `spacy` to parse a CSV. It is for *natural language text parsing* Were you just trying to see how it would handle something like this?  But in that case, why were you expecting anything at all?

Comment: well, if you are interested, I'm trying to convert the csv, which is 'structured', into unstructured text.  but I want to retain the classification of the column headers, because it is a one--to-one relation. So I am not using spaCy to parse a csv, per se; I am using spaCy model to parse a csv in an intelligent way.  this way, I can build up models for various domains, run the same python, and get unstructured text, while retaining the various classification systems.

Answer (score 1):

Most issues are due to not understanding how `trained_nlp()` parses the csv str. It's pretty clear that it parses the csv str differently than you're expecting.

You should debug `trained_nlp()` to understand how exactly it parses the csv str.

> I was expecting something like:

`print("message")` by default adds a newline via a default arg, i.e. by default it does `print("message", end="\n")`.

To change that: `print("message", end='')`

Comment: You are correct.  I do not understand how trained_nlp() parses the csv string. Is there a debug flag that lets me step through the parsing?  Or just set a breakpoint in PyCharm?

Comment: also wonder how to apply print("message", end='').  Do I change: print(s) or one of the other print statements, like print ( sentence_origin + ent.label_ + ' of ' + ent.text)

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but your second comment tells me the overall problem might be beyond your current proficiency. I'd suggest reviewing & practicing Python basics and tackling a problem that's only incrementally more difficult.

Comment: I'm really just looking for an answer.  I recognize the print() is the same as pintln in other language, i.e. that it adds a line. Not so interested in that.  What I want to know are the questions I asked: 1) why does it classify the first line, even though it doesn't match the pattern 2) why does it truncate the South Carolina, but not Boykin Spaniel and 3) why do row 1 and 2 print an empty has an ORIGIN of .  If you'd like to help me with that, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: The first place to look has already been answered: looks like due to how `trained_nlp()` operates. Note StackOverflow discourages asking multiple questions in one question.